# iPhone-5 compatible issue

Tags: iphone-5, iphone-4

I had developed an ios app for ios 4.0.That was navigation based application.Now I want it also support for iPhone-5 I think I changed xib after checking device version,I am facing problem xib is changed but it's view Height is not changed.How it can possible if some else face this problem please share ideas with me.Thanks.

Comment: I noticed one more thing That size of window is different in both devices so How I can mange that this app run on Both devices.

Comment: Did you try using Autolayout? Check out my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set iOS 6 as the Base SDK and use the Auto Layout feature to make screens that can scale for all type of screens. You'll need Xcode 4.5 to do this.

Get started with Auto Layout here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

If you still want to support iOS 4.0, have separate .xib files for different screen sizes and load them appropriately at launch.

To load different nib files based on your screen size, in your app delegate, you will need to add/replace the following code in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_4inch" bundle:nil];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}
```

where `ViewController_4inch` is the name of the nib file that is designed for iPhone 5 screen

Answer (score 1):

IN APP Delegate:-

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{



CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

//----------------HERE WE SETUP FOR IPHONE 4/4s/iPod----------------------

if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){


   self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ViewController_4inch" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"iPhone 4: %f", iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);

}

//----------------HERE WE SETUP FOR IPHONE 5----------------------

if(iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ViewController_5inch" bundle:nil];
     NSLog(@"iPhone 5: %f", iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);

}

 return YES;
 }
```

Its Works !!!!!!