# UIView for iphone5 and iphone4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have created a `UIView`, with two `xibs` to support to iphone5 and iphone4. The view width is (iphone5 - 470) and (iphone5 - 400). I have initialized this view with checking the conditions for iphone5 or iphone4. But while running the app, it seems to take the iphone5.

```
CategoryView *puzzleView = [[CategoryView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, startY, levelScrollView.frame.size.width, 190)];
BOOL isiPhone = IS_IPHONE5([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
if (isiPhone)
{
    puzzleView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CategoryView5"  owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
else 
{
    puzzleView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CategoryView-iphone"  owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Please check the code here:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630851/iphone-5-compatible-issue/15894492#15894492

Answer (score 1):

The probles lies in this line:

```
BOOL isiPhone = IS_IPHONE5([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

No you are just checking wether the `size.height` is not `0`

Change into something like :

```
BOOL isiPhone = IS_IPHONE5([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 480.f);
```

Bout one should not do it like this. Just make one view and let it grow with the screen size is a better option. Just incase Apple ever decide to add an other screen size you will not have to change anything in your code.